# Is there a way to force `vue-cli-service build` to fail when some env variables are not set?

Tags: vue.js, build, environment-variables, vue-cli

I use a standard `.env` file to store env variables and `config.ts` file where those variables are used. Some of them are required. I would like to ensure that the build fails when the required variables are not set.

I there a way how to achieve it? Just using `vue-cli-service`?

The only way I can think of now is to do a simple check in the `config.ts`:

```
if(!process.env.VUE_APP_REQUIRED_VAR) {
   throw new Error('Missing required env variable: VUE_APP_REQUIRED_VAR');
}
```

But the exception will be thrown in runtime. Not during the build phase.

The reason behind is that many times I was solving a reported bug by a tester and found out that some env variable was not set.

@Note: Sure, I can do some prebuild steps in the pipeline, but I'd like to have it part of the local build process.

Comment: Create your own build script which does whatever check(s) you want, then, if all is good, it calls vue's build command. You set it to run when you call `npm run build` in package.json>scripts. While this is not directly part of vue's default build, it should be quite simple to implement.

Comment: Thanks, I did so. I hoped for a better solution. Since this requires to have another file with env variables listed and this again opens room for errors like 'I forgot to add it there.'.